# I can't get Chinese characters from MYSQL to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I found a lot of answers for my problem but nothing worked.
I have Chinese characters in my MYSQL database and when I SELECT my field in php I get '???' instead of '我们的产品'. I was able to INSERT this characters from php to my MYSQL database.

With characters like 'éà' I have no problem to get them in PHP.

My database, table and field are encoded in utf8_unicode_ci. There is my php file(also encoded in utf-8) :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($query))
echo ($arr['field']);
?>
```

If I replace my code like this it prints 我们的产品 :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT '我们的产品'");
arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)
echo ($arr[0]);
```

I hope I gave enough information.

Comment: The mysql_* functions are deprecated. see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set charset as utf8 before making a mysql query, like this

```
mysql_connect('localhost','mysql_user','your_password');
mysql_select_db('my_db') or die( "Unable to select database");
mysql_set_charset('UTF8');
mysql_query('Your query here');
```

Comment: @chokichoc, great, though I agree with VolkerK that mysql_* functions are deprecated, it would be better to switch to PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: For Chinese, utf8mb4 would be better.  Some characters exist only in utf8mb4.